# Eigenvalues of Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P= P^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).

Prove that there exists a diagonal, invertible matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that the matrix

$$ D^{\top} \, P \, D $$

has (positive) [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) such that the maximum eigenvalue is less than $2$ times the minimum eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true. Suppose $\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&d}$ is positive definite. Then its maximum eigenvalue is less than the double of its minimum eigenvalue if and only if
$$
a+d + \sqrt{(a-d)^2 + 4b^2} < 2\left(a+d - \sqrt{(a-d)^2 + 4b^2}\right),\tag{1}
$$
meaning that $9\left[(a-d)^2+4b^2\right]<(a+d)^2$, or $8(a-d)^2+36b^2<(a+d)^2-(a-d)^2$, or
$$
2(a-d)^2 + 9b^2 \le ad.\tag{2}
$$
Now consider $P=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}$. By scaling $D$, we may assume that $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,x)$ or $\operatorname{diag}(x,1)$ for some $x\ne0$. Therefore
$$
D^\top PD = \pmatrix{2&x\\ x&x^2} \text{ or } \pmatrix{2x^2&x\\ x&1}.
$$
In both cases, we would have $9b^2 > ad$ in $(2)$, regardless of $x$. Hence $(2)$ can never be satisfied. According to WolframAlpha, the minimum ratio is $3+2\sqrt{2}$ when [$D=\operatorname{diag}(1,x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20%28x%5E2%2B2%2Bsqrt%28x%5E4%2B4%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2-sqrt%28x%5E4%2B4%29%29) or [$D=\operatorname{diag}(x,1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20%282*x%5E2%2B1%2Bsqrt%284*x%5E4%2B1%29%29%2F%282*x%5E2%2B1-sqrt%284*x%5E4%2B1%29%29).